# How can I remove water from OpenStreetMap ways?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I'd like to get the outline of San Francisco from OpenStreetMap. There's a [relation for SF](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/111968), but it includes large amounts of water which would make it unrecognizable to a resident of the city:

[image: Outline of SF from OSM]

Is there a better polygon for San Francisco in OSM? Are there ways for the coastlines and, if so, how might I find them and subtract them from the administrative boundary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this using [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson) and [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). First I grabbed the full OSM XML for the San Francisco relation and converted it to GeoJSON:

```
$ curl 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/111968/full' > sf.osm
$ osmtogeojson sf.osm > sf.json
```

Then I removed the non-polygon features using [this script](https://gist.github.com/danvk/57c3164d3c65a4f7a4f6):

```
$ only_polygons.py sf.json > sf.polygons.json
```

Then I downloaded the [land polygons file](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons) that Tordanik referenced and ran:

```
$ ogr2ogr land_polygons.sfbbox.shp -clipsrc -122.56 37.68 -122.27 37.939 land-polygons-complete-4326/land_polygons.shp
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON sf-land.json -clipsrc sf.polygons.json land_polygons.sfbbox.shp
```

This produces a GeoJSON file (`sf-land.json`) with the land boundaries of San Francisco:

[image: SF boundary, snug to the coastline]

I'm not sure where the Farallon Islands went, but this basically seems to work!

Every step of this is fast except for the first `ogr2ogr` command, which clips the land polygons to a bounding box containing San Francisco. This took ~2 minutes on my MacBook Pro. This way was dramatically fast than passing sf.polygons.json directly as the `-clipsrc` argument to the first command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways for the [coastline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline). For example [this way](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/40500809#map=12/37.6772/-123.0501) which is also part of the relation but also [this way](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/28671927) which is obviously not part of the relation. Therefore I think it is very challenging to mechanically remove all water and smaller islands but not impossible. I guess you would have to retrieve all map [data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) inside the polygon and run some spatial queries.

The relation you are looking at defines the administrative border of San Francisco. The relation you are looking for would be San Fransisco's landmass without the water (and probably without the smaller islands belonging to San Francisco). Such relations usually don't exist in OSM.

Comment: There is also coastline data available here which might be easier to work with: http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons

Comment: @scai can you say more about how you found that coastline way? It seems like [this overpass query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4A6) should bring it up, but it doesn't.

Comment: @danvk By opening the [data layer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Browsing#The_data_browser) :)

Try [this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4Am) instead, yours seems to contain a wrong recursion step.

Comment: Improvement thanks to the Wizard (coastline in San Francisco) http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4Cc For all the county (so all the islands come selected) http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4Cd